# Grails Spring Security Login/Logout Controllers not generated

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am trying to learn Grails along with the Spring Security plugin. I am using Grails 2.3.0 with springsecurity-RC2 plugin and following the guide on the Grails website.

The issue I am running into is that the generated LoginController.groovy and LogoutController.groovy files from the s2-quickstart script are not being generated in the grails-app/controller, instead they are in target/work/springsecurity/grails-app/controller.

This issue does not seem to occur in grails 2.1.5 but does in 2.2.4.
Is there anyway for me to fix these issues or do I not need them?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is by design. The files aren't generated anymore, they're included in the plugin itself. If you need to modify them, copy the controller and/or GSPs to your project in the same location under grails-app and make your changes there. Apps can always override plugin classes using this approach since Grails compiles plugins first, then the app.

Comment: Thanks, still very new to Grails and did not know about this.

Comment: Though the nature of Grails encourages this, I would have loved to read about these changes in the "What's New in Version 2.0" guide.

Comment: Great.. Simple and straight forward. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Broken link :(  Grails info becomes out of date so quickly...  Also in Grails 3 where do you copy these files from?