# How to get the reason of login failure in clients while using Grails Spring Security Rest plugin?

Tags: rest, grails, spring-security, spring-security-rest

We are using Grails Spring Security Rest plugin 1.5.2 with Grails 2.5.2.

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to report any reason of why a login failure occurred. The only thing we get from the login request is `HTTP 401`.

We have a mechanism where after a number of login failures we set the `accountLocked` property of the `User`, so the account becomes disabled/locked.

We would like to get at least a JSON response of why the login failed, like "User account is locked", "Bad credentials", "No such user", etc.

Is there a way to do this with current versions that we use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin doesn't support that out of the box. However, you can easily workaround it by replacing [RestAuthenticationFailureHandler](https://github.com/alvarosanchez/grails-spring-security-rest/blob/develop/src/groovy/grails/plugin/springsecurity/rest/RestAuthenticationFailureHandler.groovy) with your own implementation and wiring it in `resources.groovy` as `restAuthenticationFailureHandler`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So the "exception" has the details of the failure and I will need to add my JSON message to the "response" object in the custom RestAuthenticationFailureHandler. Right?

Comment: It would be any `org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException`, eg, `org.springframework.security.authentication.LockedException`.

Comment: I do it. It works but I cant add any body to the response...
When I add header it works fine, but I never receive anything in response.body when I try response.getWriter().write("{\"error\" : ${e.message}"); in my custom restAuthenticationFailureHandler
Any idea ?

Comment: It's hard to tell from here. Did you set also the `Content-Type` header of the response? Otherwise some clients might be unable to read the body